# Why decimals do not interoperate with floats

Tags: python, decimal

[Notes on Decimal](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/numbers.py#L24) says:

```
## Decimal has all of the methods specified by the Real abc, but it should
## not be registered as a Real because decimals do not interoperate with
## binary floats (i.e.  Decimal('3.14') + 2.71828 is undefined).  But,
## abstract reals are expected to interoperate (i.e. R1 + R2 should be
## expected to work if R1 and R2 are both Reals).
```

I don't understand why `Decimal('3.14') + 2.71828 is undefined`. Decimal [can be constructed](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) from a float so I think that `__add__` can be implemented as follows:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, float):
        return self + Decimal(other)
    ...
```

With it we will be able to get `Decimal('3.14') + 2.71828 = Decimal('3.14') + Decimal(2.71828) = 5.858280000000000153903556566`

Can you explain why they do not interoperate in current implementation?

EDIT: it is possible to save precision when converting float to decimal with converting it to str first:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, float):
        return self + Decimal(str(other))
    ...
```

Thus `Decimal('3.14') + 2.71828 = Decimal('3.14') + Decimal('2.71828') = 5.85828` without losing precision.

Comment: To prevent exactly that kind of thing. The error forces you to think about what value you actually want, so you don't accidentally and unexpectedly lose the precision you were using Decimal for in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key is in the way that the `Decimal` is initialized.

Notice how in all the examples in the documentation, `Decimal` is made from a `string`. 
It allows us to pass a number without loosing precision when storing it.

```py
number = Decimal('1.1')
print(number)
```

The output of the code above will always be `Decimal('1.1')`

Altough initalizing `Decimal` with a `float` is possible, we lose the very thing we want to achieve by using `Decimal` in the first place, precision. Consider the following line of code.

```py
number = Decimal(1.1)
```

What's the values inside the `number`? In my instance, the output is

```py
Decimal('1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625')
```

`1.1` is stored in a `float`, which means it loses precision. Then we use that to initialize a `Decimal`. That's why you should be initializing `Decimals` using `string`, not `float`, to avoid losing precision, which is the whole point of using `Decimal` in the first place anyways.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited my question with better implementation of `__add__`, which doesn't lose precision on at least some inputs. Can you please check the updated version? Are there still any problems with it?

Comment: You're missing the point, the problem is not with initializing a `Decimal` with `float` instead of `string`, but with holding the temporary value that will be used to initialize in a `float` at any point, as it will most likely change the value, as not all numbers can be represented as a `float'`. 

While `str(1.1)` will in fact give `'1.1'`, `str(0.1 + 0.2)` will output something along the lines of `'0.30000000000000004'`, meaning we lost precision again, and initializing a `Decimal` with it will still have the `float` rounding error.

Comment: Not to get `'0.30000000000000004'` we can do `Decimal(str(0.1)) + Decimal(str(0.2))`. That said, we must convert float to str immediately, without doing `Decimal(<float>)` or `<float> + <float>`.

Comment: Also the problem of summation of two floats like `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.300000000004` is not really related to the summation of Decimal and float.

Comment: `str(float)` won't always give you the exact number your typed in, consider `Decimal('10.000000000000001') == Decimal(str(10.000000000000001))` giving `False`, even if we immediately used `str` on a `float`

Comment: Good example. After it I don't have any further questions on this topic. Thank you.